# Clone the Andriod version from Samsung to Lenovo?

Tags: android-versions

I bought this Lenovo K10a40, and I bought just problems.
This will be a number 2 phone if I can get it work in a reliable state.

I have been looking a little around and if I could downgrade it to clone of the Android 4.2.2 on an old simple Samsung GT-S7580 it would really work as an upgrade. If that is impossible any change to the better would be OK to test. Else the phone is just garbage, I cant trust it.

I am totally green on this, and do not even know how to root a phone. Among the problems with the Lenovo, I got MMS problems, Bluetooth problems, and I miss the native android sip client.

As you understand  I need a detailed description of every steps I have to do.

Thank you
dsk

Answer (score 2):

Android version are always device specific. Therefore you can't use Android from device X and copy/clone it to a different device Y.

The main reason for this is that each Android version contains a number a device drivers for all the different components (graphics chip, GPS, camera, sensors, hardware keys, main CPU). Each driver has to be the correct driver in the correct version configured in a correct way. Otherwise nothing will work

If you have problems with a new Android device there is only one way: Check on https://lineageos.org if there is a custom ROM version for your device. With a little bit of luck such a version exists and there is a way to install it on your devices. Note that installing a custom ROM results in loosing the warranty for your device. If something goes wrong with the installation of the custom ROM there is always the chance to brick the device.